# How to save MultiSelect values in MultiStep react form using hooks

Tags: reactjs, multi-select

I have developed multistep form in react. When i create multiselect option in form the value is not saved in states. I am using hooks. When i select options and click on next page the values is not saved in array. 
Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState }   from 'react';   
import Select, { components } from 'react-select';
const UserDetails = ({ setForm, formData, navigation }) => {   
    const techCompanies = [
        { label: "Apple", value: 1 },
        { label: "Facebook", value: 2 },
        { label: "Netflix", value: 3 },
        { label: "Tesla", value: 4 },
        { label: "Amazon", value: 5 },
        { label: "Alphabet", value: 6 },
      ];
      const [selectedOption,setselectedOption] = useState([]);
      const [newarray,setarray]=useState([]);

     const  handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
        setselectedOption(newarray.concat(selectedOption))
        console.log(setselectedOption)
    }
      console.log(selectedOption)

    const { next } = navigation;  
    return( 
        <div className="row justify-content-center mt-5">
            <form>  
             <h1 className="text-center prox_bold">Enter User Details</h1>
                 <Select 
                  options={ techCompanies }
                  isMulti
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={selectedOption}/>   
                  <div className="row justify-content-center mt-5">
                   <button className="btn green_btn w250 font22" onClick={next}>
                       Next
                   </button>    
               </div>       
           </form>
         </div>
    );
}
export default UserDetails;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The state is local to the `UserDetails` component. Whatever logic you have in `next()` appears to be selectively rendering `UserDetails` depending on which step the user has reached.

This is a problem because when the user moves to the next step, your `UserDetails` is unmounted and destroyed and therefore loses its state.

The solution is to have the `selectedOption` array as a prop on `UserDetails`, and move the `handleChange` up into the parent component and have that as a prop on `UserDetails` as well. Store `selectedOption` in the state of the parent component which doesn't unmount on change of step.

```
<UserDetails ... selectedOption={parentStateSelectedOption} handleChange={handleChange} />
```

In the `<Select />`:

```
<Select ... value={parentStateSelectedOption} onChange={handleChange}
                                                        ^ parent handleChange not local
```

In your parent component, put the `handleChange` event so it stores in the parent state.

Now, as the user moves to the next screen, you have safely stored the selected options in the parent state.